# Tensorflow: Create dataset from array of Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to create a *tf.data.Dataset* from unknown number of Tensors.

Each tensor is contained in an hdf5 file. 
The number of tensors will be determined at runtime. 
Also, there is a pair relationship for each tensor. This has to be kept in the dataset.

The current attempt:

```py
import deepdish as dd

def createDatasets(n_files):
  d = []
  r = []
  for i in range(n_files):
    d.append( (dd.io.load('../data/prepared/clean_'+str(i)+'.h5')['dataset'], dd.io.load('../data/prepared/dirty_'+str(i)+'.h5')['dataset']) )
    r.append(d[i][1])
  both = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tuple(d))
  rfi = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(tuple(r))
  return both, rfi
```

The issue is that these tuples are stored as a *single entry* in the Dataset. 
i.e. The Cardinality of each data set is always 1 despite the number of tensors used.

```py
>>> both, rfi = createDatasets(5)
>>> rfi
<TensorDataset shapes: ((100, 15, 4096, 4), (100, 15, 4096, 4), (100, 15, 4096, 4), (100, 15, 4096, 4), (100, 15, 4096, 4)), types: (tf.complex64, tf.complex64, tf.complex64, tf.complex64, tf.complex64)>
>>> dataset_length = [i for i,_ in enumerate(rfi)][-1] + 1
>>> print(dataset_length)
1
```

In effect what I would like to accomplish is to 'remove the outer brackets' for the shapes and types.

Comment: Maybe you want [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) instead?